# Setup Auto-Response Rule when using Email-to-case for emails not related to an existing case

Tags: apex-email-service

We have a specific workflow where most messages send to support and our other address is specifically given to the client once they have signed up and we email them directly. I am trying to setup an Auto-Response Rule to reply to clients who have emailed in to our address directly rather than replying or when they should be emailing our support address.

I am using Email-to-case and would like to set this rule up to send out when the case is opened. I went to settings>Customize>Cases>Auto-Response Rules and created the rule and set it active. I set the criteria to reply to any case with the origin of my address and created less than 180 seconds ago. cases are still creating but the auto-response is not sending.

Any help?

Comment: facing the same issue, did you able to achieve this?